# Django. Should I use ForeignKey or Addtional Cross Table for one to many relation?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm aware of this question was asked before, but that question doesn't have concise answer for my problem. I'm bit confused after seeing two examples in order to  impelement OneToManyRelation.

In my example:

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Advantages(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, CASCADE)
```

Different products can have many advantages linked to it, so I'm using ForeignKey for this, but here I saw that it is also possible to use cross table relation in order to implement OneToManyRelation

[categories & sub categories with many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128560/categories-sub-categories-with-many-to-many-relationship)

```
class ProductAdvantage(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, CASCADE)
```

Which one best practice for the OneToManyRelation? One product can have many advantages
Thank you for the answer

Comment: Read this [what does on_delete=models.PROTECT and on_delete=models.CASCADE do on Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502537/what-does-on-delete-models-protect-and-on-delete-models-cascade-do-on-django-mod)

Comment: what does this have to do with my question?

Comment: There is no difference between your examples other than the class name and the `PROTECT`/`CASCADE` value for the `on_delete` argument. Please refine your question as it is not clear what are you asking about.

Comment: @GwynBleidD. Let me clarify. I want to strucuture database for product and category. Product can link to many categories. So how I strucure such database table?

Comment: Please edit the question and fix your examples, as they are misleading. For your question itself, it's still unclear to me what other database design do you mean as an alternative to the first example in your question.